# Sequence $1, {1\over2}, {1\over4}, {3\over4}, {1\over8}, {3\over8}, {5\over8}, {7\over8}, ...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone help me with this sequence? To what converges for? I'm trying to get it in terms of $m,n$, such that ${2m+1\over2^n}$ or something similar.

Can it be written in a general form even if it does not converge?

Comment: It does not converge, as the tail contains numbers arbitrarily close to the bounds of $0$ and $1$

Comment: Expanding on Henry's comment. Consider the subsequence $1,1/2,1/4,1/8,1/16,\ldots \rightarrow 0$. Consider also the subsequence $1,1/2,3/4,7/8,15/16,\ldots\rightarrow 1$. Since the subsequences of a convergent sequence all converge to the same point, the original sequence cannot be convergent.

Comment: Ok, I see it. Is it possible to write it in a general form in terms of m and n, even if it does not converge?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible using a single parameter only, but it's probably annoying. I'd start by (assuming the sequence starts with $n=1$ or $0$, whichever is more convenient) trying to figure out for which $n$ the terms have the form $\frac{1}{2^k}$, and $\frac{2^k-1}{2^k}$; there should be a decent relationship between $n$ and $k$. I think it'll still be a lot of work for a general formula, but if nothing else, you'll have found two subsequences converging to different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add numerator and denominator you get the sequence : $1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,...$

So if $c_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ then $a_n+b_n=2n+1$.

We have that $b_n$ is a power of $2$ and $\displaystyle b_n=2^m$ for $2^{m-1}\le n<2^m$

Taking the logarithm of that $m-1\le \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(2)}<m$ which is $m=\lfloor\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(2)}\rfloor+1$

I propose the formula $c_0=1$ and $\forall n\ge 1$
$$c_n=\frac{2n+1-2^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor+1}}{2^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor+1}}$$

Comment: Thanks. I never thought it was be possible!